# Does "imshow()" matplolib function work in Django (Apache 2.2 server and wsgi python mod)?

Tags: django, apache2, matplotlib, mod-wsgi

I'm trying to generate a dynamic chart using Django with imshow() function:

My code is something like this:

```
    ... <here django imports> ...

    from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter

fig=Figure()
ax=fig.add_subplot(111)
x,y = ogrid[-1.:1.:.01, -1.:1.:.01]

z = 3*y*(3*x**2-y**2)/4 + .5*cos(6*pi * sqrt(x**2 +y**2) + arctan2(x,y))



ax.imshow(z, origin='lower', extent=[-1,1,-1,1])

# Plotting contour lines
ax.contour(z, origin='lower', extent=[-1,1,-1,1])

xlabel('x')
ylabel('y')
title('A spiral !')


ax.plot(x[:], z[50, :])

canvas=FigureCanvas(fig)
response=django.http.HttpResponse(content_type='image/png')
canvas.print_png(response)
return response
```

I'm using Apache server with mod wsgi for python. And when I execute this snippet it seems to enter in an infinite loop (no image is shown). On the other hand, if I execute it in the python console directly, it works like a charm. What's happening?

Note: If I delete the "imshow()" line, it also works in web mode. Is imshow() saving some content (maybe cache) and i should give permission in Apache httpd.conf?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting:

```
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
```

Can't remember if matplotlib has issue with sub interpreters, or whether it is because of trying to fork processes.